# draw function not looping as expected

Tags: javascript, loops, random, refresh, draw

I'm a beginner on here, so apologies in advance for naivety. I've made a simple image on Brackets using Javascript, trying to generate circles with random x and y values, and random colours. There are no issues showing when I open the browser console in Developer Tools, and when I save and refresh, it works. But I was expecting the refresh to happen on a loop through the draw function. Any clues as to where I've gone wrong?

Thanks so much

```
var r_x
var r_y
var r_width
var r_height
var x
var y
var z


function setup() 
{
    r_x = random()*500;
    r_y = random()*500;
    r_width = random()*200;
    r_height = r_width;
    x = random(1,255);
    y= random(1,255);
    z= random(1,255);

    createCanvas(512,512);
    background(255);

}

function draw()
{

    ellipse(r_x, r_y, r_width, r_height);
    fill(x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: can you share your `window.onload = function()` - that's where the magic should happen

Comment: This is where I reveal just how inexperienced I am - this is day 3, and I have not come across anything resembling that yet... Could it be inbuilt, as part of brackets.io's internal workings? The folder I've been working from contains 2 other files - index.html and p5.min.js. Neither contain window.onload = function(). The whole thing started life as a file provided for a specific coding exercise, so perhaps that explains it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets.io is just your text editor (or IDE if you want to be technical) - so we can remove that from the equation. The next thing that baffles me is that something has to explicitly call your `draw()` method as well as the `setup()` method -

I'm thinking that you're working in some sort of library created to simplify working with the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) because in the `setup()` method you're calling `createCanvas(xcord,ycord)` and that doesn't exist on it's own. If you want to rabbit hole on that task check out this [medium article](https://codeburst.io/creating-and-drawing-on-an-html5-canvas-using-javascript-93da75f001c1), it walks you thru all the requirements for creating a canvas element and then drawing on that canvas

Your also confirming that you're drawing at least 1 circle on browser refresh so i think all you need to focus on is 1)initiating your code on load and 2)a loop, and we'll just accept there is magic running in the background that will handle everything else.

At the bottom of the file you're working in add this:

```
// when the page loads call drawCircles(), 
// i changed the name to be more descriptive and i'm passing in the number of circles i want to draw, 
// the Boolean pertains to event bubbling  
window.addEventListener("load", drawCircles(73), false);
```

In your `drawCircles()` method you're going to need to add the loop:

```
// im using a basic for loop that requires 3 things:
// initialization, condition, evaluation
// also adding a parameter that will let you determine how many circles you want to draw
function drawCircles(numCircles) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numCircles; i++) {
    ellipse(r_x, r_y, r_width, r_height);
    fill(x, y, z);
  }
}
```

here's a [link to a codepen](https://codepen.io/mcgraw/collab/QOgWwB) that i was tinkering with a while back that does a lot of the same things you are

I hope that helps - good luck on your new learning venture, it's well worth the climb!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help! What you say makes sense - I basically deleted the equivalent amount of code from a little training exercise downloaded through coursera, thinking that I could then essentially use it as an empty sandpit to play in. But there's clearly far more going on under the hood!

Thanks again!

Comment: if the answer is helpful or what you need click accept answer button